# How can I get visualization of folder sizes within OneDrive folder?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

My usual tactic for getting visualization of the relative sizes of folders is to use the free tool SpaceSniffer which presents a handy interactive box view of the sizes of folders and subfolders making it easy to see where large parts of the hard drive are used.

However, the local OneDrive folder seems to be inaccessible to the SpaceSniffer, even when OneDrive is stopped and the SpaceSniffer is running as Administrator. Sometimes the OneDrive folder takes up a large percentage of a hard drive which makes the SpaceSniffer much less useful.

Is there a way grant access to the local OneDrive folder for SpaceSniffer or an alternative tool or strategy to get a similar visualization that includes the contents of the local OneDrive folder?

I am only interested in the usage of the local hard drive and so files that exist in the cloud service but don't have local hard drive space allocated are fine to ignore for the purpose of this visualization.

Comment: Because OneDrive files and folders don't fully exist on the local drives, software for checking file/folder sizes would need to be able to access the cloud data itself. This usually means the app needs to be able to open the cloud service and query its data. Unless the app is designed to do this from the group up it is likely not simple to add this capability.

Comment: To clarify - I'm only interested in the usage of the local hard drive, not the data in OneDrive cloud storage. Files that exist in the cloud service but don't have local hard drive space allocated are fine to ignore for the purpose of this visualization. I just want to see what is on the current hard drive. I will update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Then all you're asking is where OneDrive stores local data, and OneDrive storea data in C:\Users\profile\OneDrive. Find that folder and you can see the total size of the local OneDrive files.

Comment: @music2myear - If only it was that easy. The problem is not that I cannot find the OneDrive folder. Nor is the problem that I can't find the total space used by the OneDrive Folder. These things are easy enough to do using in built windows exploerer functions. What I want is SpaceSniffer to create a visualization of the full drive and folder hierarchy but I find that OneDrive folders are excluded because access is denied. The question is: How can I include them in the visualization?

Comment: What account is the application running as? Can you access the folder yourself? Have you tried different apps?

Comment: The application is running as my local administrator account. I can access the folders with the same account using Windows Explorer.

Comment: Ok, I'm even more confused, or you haven't given us all of the information yet. I just ran my preferred disk space visualizer, WizTree, and your SpaceSniffer on my C:\Users\user\OneDrive and it showed everything just fine. No special permission or settings needed. I'm running Windows 10, fully updated. I didn't have to shut OneDrive down or do anything but point the app at the folder.

Comment: What leads you to believe the folder uses a large percentage of your drive when your app cannot show you what's in it?

Comment: @music2myear Ah - that's a good point. I was trying to scan the whole drive in one go - and when I do this the OneDrive folder is omitted from the SpaceSniffer UI (it all goes into "Not Yet Scanned" and stays there - but if I scan the OneDrive folder directly by providing the full path to it then it works and I can see the structure inside. An odd glitch, but one that can be worked around. If you put that as an answer I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointing the application to the specific OneDrive folder should allow it to scan the contents and report the structure and size as desired.